# Elasticsearch itself ignores the special characters in query string. How can i avoid that?

Tags: elasticsearch, special-characters, exact-match

I have to search some particular query_string with special character but it gives me all the results.

When i analyze it by:

```
GET /exact/_analyze
{
  "field": "subject",
  "text": "abdominal-scan"
}
```

output is like:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "abdominal",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "scan",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

This means that is automatically skipping the hyphen(-) and considering these words as 2 words.

If i change the indexing of the field as not_analyzed then i am not able to search a single word in that field whole sentence has to be passed in query_string.

Is there any other alternative so that i can get exact search(without ignoring the special characters)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at the [definitive guide's section about analysis](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html) as this is very important to understand the behavior of your index.

By default, your field is analyzed using the [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html), which splits words on hyphen.

A very simple analyzer to understand is the [whitespace analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html), which splits input into tokens on the whitespace characters.

You can try this example :

```
POST /solution
{
  "mappings":{
    "doc": {
      "properties":{
        "subject": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

GET /solution/_analyze
{
  "field": "subject",
  "text": "This is about abdominal-scan"
}
```

which outputs :

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "This",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "is",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "about",
      "start_offset": 8,
      "end_offset": 13,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "abdominal-scan",
      "start_offset": 14,
      "end_offset": 28,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see that your hyphen is preserved in this case.